# Regular expression to add a word between html-tags (newbie)

Tags: html, regex, notepad++

I can't seem to create a regular expression that would work in this situation:

I have hundreds of lines that look like this:

```
<a title="Match" href="http://mywebsite.com/category/Match"></a>
```

I would need to have the title word inserted between the html tags, like so:

```
<a title="Match" href="http://mywebsite.com/category/Match">Match</a>
```

Here's my feeble attempt at it (using Notepad++):

```
Find:
 title="([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*?)"([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*?)><

Replace:
 title="\1"\2>\1<
```

As you can see, I really suck at regular expressions :D

Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT:

I should clarify that this is a one-time operation carried out in Notepad++ with the find and replace panel.

I should also clarify that the word "Match" is going to be different on each line.

Comment: Obligatory: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/284111

Comment: @zespri there is no XML/HTML parser in Notepad++. Nice try though.

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ: That reminds me a recent dialogue with my son. "Dad I can't put my seat-belt on! That's because you are doing it with one hand. Use your both hands. But I'm holding this toy in one of my hands! Then you have to put the toy down, use your both hands to buckle up and then pick the toy up".

Comment: @zespri it would be more like "Son, put your seatbelt on!" his response is "Dad!? I'm on my bike!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works in *Notepad++ 6.3.2*

**Find what :**

```
(title\=")([^"]+)("[^>]+>)(<)
```

**Replace with :**

```
\1\2\3\2\4
```

Answer (score 0):

### Use Capture Groups and Back-References

You can capture parts of your match using capture groups, and then replace them with back-references. The specific syntax may vary by language and implementation. Here are two examples.

#### Ruby Example

```
str = %q{<a title="Match" href="http://mywebsite.com/category/Match"></a>}
str.sub /(Match)(">)</, "#{$1}#{$2}#{$1}<"
# => "<a title=\"Match\" href=\"http://mywebsite.com/category/Match\">Match</a>"
```

#### GNU sed Example

```
$ echo '<a title="Match" href="http://mywebsite.com/category/Match"></a>' |
    sed -r 's/(Match)(">)</\1\2\1</'
<a title="Match" href="http://mywebsite.com/category/Match">Match</a>
```

Comment: Notepad++ is in Windows.

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ So is [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/). Windows is not an excuse not use have Ruby or GNU sed available.

Comment: I know, I run all sorts of OSes, but I'm not the average computer user. :) Just figured rather than having to say "Install a bunch of other stuff because I don't know your program, then pick my solution." it was easier to give the solution in the OP's app of choice.

Comment: Anyone interested can get sed for Windows from here: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm